# how to move divs using jQuery and pick one randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a quiz in which visitors subscribe using their name and phone numbers.

Then I will have to make a live streaming to select a winner (randomly). So I want to make an animated page to achieve that.

I have a set of divs, each single div contains the name of the visitor and his phone number.

When I open the page the divs by default should move very quickly inside the winner div (take a look at the code) from the top to the bottom so I can not distinguish or read what's written inside the div when I press any key or button it should stop and show me the winner div (that contains the winner information).

This is my html:

```html
<div id="winner">
    <div class="visitor_details"> Name:Petter , Phone: 888.888.888</div>
    <div class="visitor_details"> Name:Jhon, Phone: 999.888.888</div>
    <div class="visitor_details"> Name:Maechl , Phone: 777.888.888</div>
    <div class="visitor_details"> Name:Ali , Phone: 666.888.888</div>
    <div class="visitor_details"> Name:Jack , Phone: 555.888.888</div>
    <div class="visitor_details"> Name:Shong , Phone: 444.888.888</div>
    <div class="visitor_details"> Name:Morad , Phone: 333.888.888</div>
    <div class="visitor_details"> Name:Smith , Phone: 222.888.888</div>
</div>
```

I didn't find any plugin who can achieve this.

thanks very much guys.

Comment: Can't you try to assign a different ID for each element and select one randomly using JScript?

Comment: [Check this out](https://github.com/joehanna/swapsies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make use of `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var winners = $('#winner .visitor_details').hide();
  var button = $('.stopbtn');
  
  var showWinner = function(winners) {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (winners.length-1));
    var winner = winners.eq(index);
    winner.show().siblings().hide();
  };
  
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    showWinner(winners);
  }, 50);
  
  button.click(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="winner">
<div class="visitor_details"> Name:Petter , Phone: 888.888.888</div>
<div class="visitor_details"> Name:Jhon, Phone: 999.888.888</div>
<div class="visitor_details"> Name:Maechl , Phone: 777.888.888</div>
<div class="visitor_details"> Name:Ali , Phone: 666.888.888</div>
<div class="visitor_details"> Name:Jack , Phone: 555.888.888</div>
<div class="visitor_details"> Name:Shong , Phone: 444.888.888</div>
<div class="visitor_details"> Name:Morad , Phone: 333.888.888</div>
<div class="visitor_details"> Name:Smith , Phone: 222.888.888</div>
</div>

<button class="stopbtn">Stop</button>
```

Comment: thank you that's what i look for i marked your comment as the answer .

Answer (score 0):

You can get random number from 0 to `visitorslength-1`

```
var randomindex = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.visitor_details').length - 1)
```

Then use that random number to target element based on index and select it as winner.

```
var winner = $('.visitor_details').eq(randomindex);
```

```js
 var randomindex = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.visitor_details').length - 1)   
 var winner = $('.visitor_details').eq(randomindex );
 alert(winner.text());
```

```html
  <div id="winner">
<div class="visitor_details"> Name:Petter , Phone: 888.888.888</div>
<div class="visitor_details"> Name:Jhon, Phone: 999.888.888</div>
<div class="visitor_details"> Name:Maechl , Phone: 777.888.888</div>
<div class="visitor_details"> Name:Ali , Phone: 666.888.888</div>
<div class="visitor_details"> Name:Jack , Phone: 555.888.888</div>
<div class="visitor_details"> Name:Shong , Phone: 444.888.888</div>
<div class="visitor_details"> Name:Morad , Phone: 333.888.888</div>
<div class="visitor_details"> Name:Smith , Phone: 222.888.888</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

<div id="winner">
<div class="visitor_details"> Name:Petter , Phone: 888.888.888</div>
<div class="visitor_details"> Name:Jhon, Phone: 999.888.888</div>
<div class="visitor_details"> Name:Maechl , Phone: 777.888.888</div>
<div class="visitor_details"> Name:Ali , Phone: 666.888.888</div>
<div class="visitor_details"> Name:Jack , Phone: 555.888.888</div>
<div class="visitor_details"> Name:Shong , Phone: 444.888.888</div>
<div class="visitor_details"> Name:Morad , Phone: 333.888.888</div>
<div class="visitor_details"> Name:Smith , Phone: 222.888.888</div>
</div>

<button class="stopbtn">Stop</button>
<style>
  .visitor_details{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid gray;
  }

  .visitor_details.active{
    background-color:green;
  }
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  var winners = $('#winner .visitor_details');
  var button = $('.stopbtn');

  var showWinner = function(winners) {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (winners.length-1));
    var winner = winners.eq(index);
    winner.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  };

  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    showWinner(winners);
  }, 500);

  button.click(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    alert("Winner is: " + $('.active').text())
  });
});
</script>
  </body>

</html>
```